# Why do Google Apps Script and Crypto.subtle generate different RSA signatures?

Tags: google-apps-script, rsa, digital-signature, subtlecrypto

I can't figure out why these two pieces of code generate different signatures when using the same message and key as inputs. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried putting \0 or \n at the end of either message.

I've tried using ASCII encoding instead of UTF-8 for Apps Script.

I've tried different salt lengths for crypto.subtle (but I think Apps Script must use salt length of 0, because it generates the same signature every time.)

## Google AppsScript

```
function testSign() {

  const message = "test";

  const key = `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
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
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
`;

  const sig = Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(message, key, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);

  console.log(sig.slice(0,4)); // [ 45, -76, -60, -59 ]

}
```

## Crypto.subtle:

```
  const message = "test";

  const pemContents = `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`;

  function str2ab(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
      bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
  }

  function importRsaKey(pemContents) {
    const binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
    const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString);
    return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "pkcs8",
      binaryDer,
      {
        name: "RSA-PSS",
        hash: "SHA-256"
      },
      true,
      ["sign"]
    );
  }

  const key = await importRsaKey(pemContents);

  const sig = await window.crypto.subtle.sign(
    {
      name: "RSA-PSS",
      saltLength: 0,
    },
    key,
    (new TextEncoder()).encode(message)
  );

  const sigArray = new Int8Array(sig);

  console.log(sigArray[0], sigArray[1], sigArray[2], sigArray[3]); // -97 -106 92 29
```

Comment: RSA-PSS includes a random component, and is considered the better choice over PKCS1 version 1.5 type 1 signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was the algorithm for crypto.subtle. Following code for crypto.subtle matches appsscript:

```
  const message = "test";

  const pemContents = `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`;

  function str2ab(str) {
    const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
    const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
      bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
  }

  function importRsaKey(pemContents) {
    const binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
    const binaryDer = str2ab(binaryDerString);
    return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
      "pkcs8",
      binaryDer,
      {
        name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
        hash: "SHA-256"
      },
      true,
      ["sign"]
    );
  }

  const key = await importRsaKey(pemContents);

  const sig = await window.crypto.subtle.sign(
    {
      name: "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5"
    },
    key,
    (new TextEncoder()).encode(message)
  );

  const sigArray = new Int8Array(sig);

  console.log(sigArray[0], sigArray[1], sigArray[2], sigArray[3]); // 45 -76 -60 -59
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I think the only thing I changed was the algorithm variant.

Google doesn't specify which version of RSA they are using, so I originally assumed RSA-PSS with no salt, based on some web searches, but it appears they are actually using RSA-SSA-PKCS1-v1_5, so swapping to that algorithm is all that is needed to make it work.